# Facebook Canvas App cant login to Developer

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-canvas

when Try to login Facebook Canvas App only Developer can't login to App Show following Error

> Invalid Scopes: read_friendlists. This message is only shown to
>   developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if
>   present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

I use Following code inside index.php file and bottom of the code

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
 appId      : '<?php echo APP_ID;?>',
 xfbml      : true,
 version    : 'v2.3'
});

function onLogin(response) {
 if (response.status == 'connected') {
  FB.api('/me?fields=first_name', function(data) {
   var welcomeBlock = document.getElementById('fb-welcome');
   welcomeBlock.innerHTML = 'Hello, ' + data.first_name + '!';
  });
 }
}

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
 // Check login status on load, and if the user is
 // already logged in, go directly to the welcome message.
 if (response.status == 'connected') {
  onLogin(response);
 } else {
  // Otherwise, show Login dialog first.
  FB.login(function(response) {
  onLogin(response);
  }, {scope: 'user_friends,email,read_friendlists'});
 }
});

FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
};

(function(d, s, id){
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

This happen on 6th of may 2015, before that it works fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link and check your api version.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3

As per this link

"If you want to access a person's friends who also use your app, you should use the `user_friends` permission.

This permission will also not help you invite a person's friends to use your app. To learn more about how to invite friends to an app, please see our FAQs.

This permission also does not give the list of friends who are part of a friendlist. It only gives access to the names of the lists.

***This permission was called `read_friendlists` before v2.3.***

**Review**

If your app requests this permission Facebook will have to review how your app uses it."